# AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?

Tags: python, linux, pip, python-3.12

Пытаюсь установить `selenium` в новый проект, который клонировал с github'a. При попытке воспользоваться встроенным *Python Packages* в *PyCharm* получаю следующее:

```
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
```

ОС: Ubuntu 22
Версия Python: 3.12.1

На [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77364550/attributeerror-module-pkgutil-has-no-attribute-impimporter-did-you-mean) есть уже такой вопрос, но там у автора стоит *Windows 11* и, несмотря на наличие ответов для linux, мне они почему-то не помогли. Я пробовал:

- `pip install --upgrade setuptools`
- `python -m pip install --user virtualenv`
- `virtualenv your_virtual_environment --python=python3.12` (с последующей активацией)
- `python3.12 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools`
  И даже
- `sudo apt install python3.12-dev`

Я не особо разбираюсь в linux, но я заметил, что при переходе на версию 3.10 (та, что стояла изначально в системе) всё корректно работает. Но мне принципиально установить версию 3.12.
Заранее спасибо

UPD:

Полный текст ошибки:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 165, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 285, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 75, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 89, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 282, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 157, in user_agent
    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/__init__.py", line 24, in get_default_environment
    from .pkg_resources import Environment
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/pkg_resources.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2164, in <module>
    register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
```

UPD2:

Установка пакетов на 3.12 корректно работает для случаев, когда я создаю новые проекты на этом ПК, но если клонирую с гита, получаю вышеописанную проблему

Comment: Похоже, в пакете `setuptools` в последней версии питона что-то поменяли. Приведите всё-таки **полный стек-трейс ошибки** в вопросе. Сейчас непонятно, кто ругается то этой ошибкой, какой конкретно код.

Comment: @CrazyElf поправил

Comment: Ну тут похоже только ждать багфиксов питона и пакетов. Сомнительно, что тут самому руками можно нормально починить что-то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На основе информации из этой статьи: [How to Install Python 3.12 on Linux Mint 21 or 20](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-python-3-12-on-linux-mint/) (должно работать и на Ubuntu)

Добавляете репозиторий deadsnakes:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
sudo apt update
```

Ставьте полный пакет `python3.12-full`:

```bash
sudo apt install python3.12-full
```

Заменять системный интерпретатор не нужно, вы так с большой вероятностью сломаете себе систему.

Далее в проекте создаете виртуальное окружение:

```bash
python3.12 -m venv .venv
```

Чтобы проверить, что все работает, активируете окружение

```bash
source .venv/bin/activate
```

Проверяете версию Python в виртуальном окружении:

```bash
> python -V
Python 3.12.1
```

Дальше открываете проект в PyCharm, он должен автоматически подхватить интерпретатор из виртуального окружения. Если не подхватится - нужно выбрать интерпретатор из виртуального окружения в настройках проекта.

Через настройки или панель Python Packages добавляете selenium (и другие нужные зависимости), должно успешно установиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот virtualenv не завелся. Его по идее нужно устанавливать глобально, но при глобальной установке вылетает та же ошибка что в вопросе. А в виртуальном окружении созданном через встроенный пакет venv с помощью pip все успешно ставится (но vitualenv в виртуальное окружение ставить - это какое-то извращение).

Comment: Большое спасибо, помог ваш вариант. У меня автоматический не смог "подхватить" интерпретатор, но если руками выбрать тот, который был создан в виртуалке, то всё сработало